# A single instance of an object at a time based the value of a specific property

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am coding an application that monitors USB drives attached to a computer and maintains a separate 'activity log' for each drive attached. I want to ensure that there is only ONE instance of the ActivityLog object (object that maintains my activity log) is present at a given time for each attached drives. This instance is created when drive is attached and destroyed when the drive is removed.

What would be an elegant way to do this? (in C#). I am thinking some combination of factory and singleton patterns (to create ActivityLog objects) but would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Fike

Comment: Is it truly a singleton? What if the drive changes, should all objects that reference the activity log be capable of accessing the new log immediately? Because else I'd suggest going for multiple instances, of which only one is 'active' at a time.

Comment: No, it is not truly a singleton. It will indeed have multiple instances. I was just thinking of using some aspects of singleton. The following answer actually provides a good resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the constructor for your `ActivityLog` object by marking it private.. then give it some "factory" abilities via a static `Get` method:

```
class ActivityLog {
    private static IDictionary<string, ActivityLog> _currentLogs = new Dictionary<string, ActivityLog>();

    private ActivityLog() {
        // your constructor code here
    }

    public static ActivityLog Get(string key) {
        if (_currentLogs.ContainsKey(key)) {
            return _currentLogs[key];
        }

        var newLog = new ActivityLog();
        _currentLogs.Add(key, newLog);

        return newLog;
    }
```

Basically, you can assign each USB device its own key (A Guid maybe instead of a string?) and call `Get` as many times as you want. Each time its called its checks the key against its internal list and either returns an already created one.. or creates one and adds its to the internal list.

If multi-threaded, you could wrap it with some locking mechanism too.

Comment: I was thinking along same lines.. Thanks for putting it so elegantly Simon.